# How to make the last image on Slideshow Carousel Automatically take Visitor To Another Web Page?

Tags: html, css, carousel

Hello I have a image slidehsow on my website and I want it setup to where when it shows the last image it automatically takes the visitor to the sign up page. What do i need to do in order to set this up?

I used a template for the slideshow that i found on youtube for the slide show and on the youtube video they called this amp story page. I copied and pasted the code below.

```css
  * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    amp-story * {
      font-family: 'Helvitica Nueve', sans-serif;
      color: white;
    }
    amp-story-page {
      background: white;
    }
    amp-story h1 {
      font-size: 46px;
    }
    amp-story h2 {
      font-size: 36px;
    }
    amp-story p {
      font-size: 16px;
      line-height: 24px;
    }
    .bold {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    .bottom {
      align-content: end;
    }
    .medium {
      font-weight: 600;
    }
    .first {
      padding-top: 65px;
    }
    .last {
      padding-bottom: 65px;
    }
    .blue {
      color: #4285F4;
    }
    .twenty-px {
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    .center {
      text-align: center;
    }
    .lh30 {
      line-height: 30px;
    }
    .icon {
      background-image: url(https://ampbyexample.com/img/AMP-Brand-White-Icon.svg);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 50px 50px;
      height: 50px;
      object-fit: contain;
      width: 50px;
    }
    .byline {
      letter-spacing: 1.28px;
      padding-bottom: 58px;
    }
    .introducing * {
      line-height: 42px;
    }
    .subtitle-page {
      padding-top: 80px;
    }
    .button {
      align-items: center;
      border: 4px solid #FFFFFF;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      display: flex;
      height: 60px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      max-width: 240px;
      text-decoration:none;
    }
    .button p {
      font-size: 20px;
      width: 100%;
    }
    amp-ad[template="image-template"] img,
    amp-ad[template="video-template"] {
      object-fit: cover;
    }
    ::cue {
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
      font-size: 24px;
      line-height: 1.5;
    }
```

```html
 
 <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
 <script async custom-element="amp-story" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-story-1.0.js"></script>
  <script async custom-element="amp-video" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-video-0.1.js"></script>

  <script async custom-element="amp-story-auto-ads" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-story-auto-ads-0.1.js"></script>
  
  
   <body>
    <amp-story standalone
      title="Key Highlights of AMP Conf 2018"
      publisher="The AMP team"
      publisher-logo-src="https://ampbyexample.com/img/AMP-Brand-White-Icon.svg"
      poster-portrait-src="https://ampbyexample.com/img/overview.jpg">
      
    <!-- <amp-story-auto-ads>
      <script type="application/json">
        {
          "ad-attributes": {
            "type": "doubleclick",
            "data-slot": "/30497360/a4a/amp_story_dfp_example"
          }
        }
      </script>
    </amp-story-auto-ads>
 -->
      
      <amp-story-page id="page-1">
        <amp-story-grid-layer template="fill">
          <amp-video autoplay loop
            width="400"
            height="750"
            poster="https://ampbyexample.com/img/poster0.png"
            layout="fill">
            <source src="https://ampbyexample.com/video/p1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          </amp-video>
        </amp-story-grid-layer>
      </amp-story-page>

      <amp-story-page id="page-2">
        <amp-story-grid-layer template="fill">
          <amp-img width="400" height="750" layout="fill" src="https://ampbyexample.com/img/overview.jpg"></amp-img>
        </amp-story-grid-layer>
        <amp-story-grid-layer template="vertical" class="bottom">
          <h2 class="bold">Overview</h2>
          <p>We held the second AMP Conf to celebrate the breadth of the AMP
            community and announce the latest AMP innovations. We engaged 400+
            devs in-person over two days and thousands globally on live stream.</p>
          <p class="last">Here are the key launches by the AMP team and others this year</p>
        </amp-story-grid-layer>
      </amp-story-page>

      <amp-story-page id="page-3">
        <amp-story-grid-layer template="fill">
          <amp-video autoplay loop
            width="400"
            height="750"
            poster="https://ampbyexample.com/img/poster.jpg"
            layout="fill">
            <source src="https://ampbyexample.com/video/stamp-animation.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          </amp-video>
        </amp-story-grid-layer>
        <amp-story-grid-layer template="vertical" class="bottom">
          <div class="introducing">
            <p class="bold blue twenty-px center">Introducing</p>
            <h2 class="bold blue center last">AMP Stories</h2>
          </div>
        </amp-story-grid-layer>
      </amp-story-page>

      <amp-story-page id="page-4">
        <amp-story-grid-layer template="fill">
          <amp-img width="400" height="750" layout="fill" src="https://ampbyexample.com/img/blue-stuff.jpg"></amp-img>
        </amp-story-grid-layer>
        <amp-story-grid-layer template="vertical" class="bottom">
          <h1 class="bold">A visual storytelling format fot the open web</h1>
          <p class="last">Providing content publishers with a mobile-focused
            format for delivering news and information as visual, tap-through
            stories on the open web.</p>
        </amp-story-grid-layer>
      </amp-story-page>

      <amp-story-page id="page-5" auto-advance-after="stamp-vid">
        <amp-story-grid-layer template="fill">
          <amp-video autoplay
            id="stamp-vid"
            width="400"
            height="750"
            poster="https://ampbyexample.com/img/poster2.jpg"
            layout="fill">
            <source src="https://ampbyexample.com/video/stamp.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <track default src="https://ampbyexample.com/video/stamp.vtt" srclang="en">
          </amp-video>
        </amp-story-grid-layer>
        <amp-story-grid-layer template="thirds">
          <div grid-area="lower-third" class="subtitle-page">
            <p class="bold twenty-px center">
              Telling stories with AMP.
            </p>
          </div>
        </amp-story-grid-layer>
      </amp-story-page>

      <amp-story-page id="page-6">
        <amp-story-grid-layer template="fill">
          <amp-video autoplay loop
            width="400"
            height="750"
            poster="https://ampbyexample.com/img/poster3.jpg"
            layout="fill">
            <source src="https://ampbyexample.com/video/gmail-animation.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          </amp-video>
        </amp-story-grid-layer>
        <amp-story-grid-layer template="vertical">
          <div class="introducing">
            <p class="bold twenty-px center first">Introducing</p>
            <h2 class="bold center">AMP For Email</h2>
          </div>
        </amp-story-grid-layer>
      </amp-story-page>

      <amp-story-page id="page-7">
        <amp-story-grid-layer template="fill">
          <amp-img width="400" height="750" layout="fill" src="https://ampbyexample.com/img/blue-gmail.jpg"></amp-img>
        </amp-story-grid-layer>
        <amp-story-grid-layer template="vertical" class="bottom">
          <h1 class="bold">Bringing the power of AMP to Gmail</h1>
          <p class="last">New spec allows developers to create more engaging,
            interactive, and actionable email experiences with AMP content.</p>
        </amp-story-grid-layer>
      </amp-story-page>

      <amp-story-page id="page-8" auto-advance-after="gmail-vid">
        <amp-story-grid-layer template="fill">
          <amp-video autoplay
            id="gmail-vid"
            width="400"
            height="750"
            poster="https://ampbyexample.com/img/poster4.jpg"
            layout="fill">
            <source src="https://ampbyexample.com/video/gmail.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <track default src="https://ampbyexample.com/video/gmail.vtt" srclang="en">
          </amp-video>
        </amp-story-grid-layer>
        <amp-story-grid-layer template="thirds">
          <div grid-area="lower-third" class="subtitle-page">
            <p class="bold twenty-px center lh30">
              AMP for Email: <br/> A New Frontier for AMP
            </p>
          </div>
        </amp-story-grid-layer>
      </amp-story-page>

      <amp-story-page id="page-9">
        <amp-story-grid-layer template="fill">
          <amp-img width="400" height="750" layout="fill" src="https://ampbyexample.com/img/green-phone.jpg"></amp-img>
        </amp-story-grid-layer>
        <amp-story-grid-layer template="vertical" class="bottom">
          <div class="introducing">
            <p class="bold twenty-px center">Discover</p>
            <h2 class="bold center last">AMP for <br/> E-Commerce</h2>
          </div>
        </amp-story-grid-layer>
      </amp-story-page>

      <amp-story-page id="page-10">
        <amp-story-grid-layer template="fill">
          <amp-img width="400" height="750" layout="fill" src="https://ampbyexample.com/img/green-stuff.jpg"></amp-img>
        </amp-story-grid-layer>
        <amp-story-grid-layer template="vertical" class="bottom">
          <h1 class="bold">Improve conversions with fast, user-friendly experiences</h1>
          <p class="last">With instant page load, your customers can find the products they want quickly and easily.</p>
        </amp-story-grid-layer>
      </amp-story-page>

      <amp-story-page id="page-11" auto-advance-after="ecomm-vid">
        <amp-story-grid-layer template="fill">
          <amp-video autoplay
            id="ecomm-vid"
            width="400"
            height="750"
            poster="https://ampbyexample.com/img/poster5.jpg"
            layout="fill">
            <source src="https://ampbyexample.com/video/ecommerce.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <track default src="https://ampbyexample.com/video/ecommerce.vtt" srclang="en">
          </amp-video>
        </amp-story-grid-layer>
        <amp-story-grid-layer template="thirds">
          <div grid-area="lower-third" class="subtitle-page">
            <p class="bold twenty-px center lh30">
              Building an AMP e-commerce Experience
            </p>
          </div>
        </amp-story-grid-layer>
      </amp-story-page>

      <amp-story-page id="page-12">
        <amp-story-grid-layer template="fill">
          <amp-img width="400" height="750" layout="fill" src="https://ampbyexample.com/img/roadshow.jpg"></amp-img>
        </amp-story-grid-layer>
        <amp-story-grid-layer template="thirds" class="bottom">
          <h1 grid-area="middle-third" class="bold">Join the worldwide AMP Roadshow</h1>
        </amp-story-grid-layer>
        <amp-story-cta-layer>
          <a href="https://www.ampproject.org" class="button medium center">
            <p class="20px">Sign up Now</p>
          </a>
        </amp-story-cta-layer>
      </amp-story-page>

      <!-- <amp-story-bookend src="https://ampbyexample.com/json/bookend.json" layout="nodisplay"></amp-story-bookend>
    </amp-story> -->
  </body>
```

Comment: I would try a solution using `window.location.href = "http://www.w3schools.com";
` shown on: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_redirect_webpage.asp

Comment: Hi, you need to show us a snippet of the code where you would sense it's the last image. Also to think through how long you want the last image to show before you take the user to another page etc. See [link]https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more help on asking a question so you can get the best help.

Comment: thanks for the advice I updated this post with some code.

Answer (score 0):

Well i actually figured out the answer. Basically you look for the Event.Listener in javascript. Then you add a function (let me know if thi is not considered a function) Below is the before and after of the javascript code.

BEFORE

```
    this.element.addEventListener('ampstory:nonextpage', function () {
            Kk(a);
        });
```

AFTER

```
    this.element.addEventListener('ampstory:nonextpage', function () {
            Kk(a);
        });
```